# Location updates using Android GPS?

Tags: android, gps, classcastexception, locationlistener

I created a class to use the LocationListener but I am getting classCastException when I request for location updates

This is my class code

```
 public class Loc implements 
    LocationListener, GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
// A request to connect to Location Services
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

// Stores the current instantiation of the location client in this object
private LocationClient mLocationClient;
/*
 * Note if updates have been turned on. Starts out as "false"; is set to
 * "true" in the method handleRequestSuccess of LocationUpdateReceiver.
 */
boolean mUpdatesRequested = false;

// Milliseconds per second
public static final int MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND = 1000;

// The update interval
public static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 10;

// A fast interval ceiling
public static final int FAST_CEILING_IN_SECONDS = 1;

// Update interval in milliseconds
public static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND
        * UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;

// A fast ceiling of update intervals, used when the app is visible
public static final long FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING_IN_MILLISECONDS = MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND
        * FAST_CEILING_IN_SECONDS;

Location currentLocation ;
LocationListener locListener;
Context x;

public Loc(Context con) {
    // Create a new global location parameters object
    this.x=con;
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();


    /*
     * Set the update interval
     */
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

    // Use high accuracy
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    // Set the interval ceiling to one minute
    mLocationRequest
            .setFastestInterval(FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING_IN_MILLISECONDS);

    // Note that location updates are off until the user turns them on
    mUpdatesRequested = false;

    /*
     * Create a new location client, using the enclosing class to handle
     * callbacks.
     */
    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(con, this, this);

}

public void stop() { // If the client is connected
    if (mLocationClient.isConnected()) {
        stopPeriodicUpdates();
    }

    // After disconnect() is called, the client is considered "dead".
    mLocationClient.disconnect();

}

public void start() {
    mLocationClient.connect();

}

public void startUpdates() {
    mUpdatesRequested = true;

    startPeriodicUpdates();
}

public Location getLocation() {

    // Get the current location
     currentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();

    // Display the current location in the UI
    Log.e("lat log", "" + currentLocation.getLatitude() + " , "
            + currentLocation.getLongitude());
    return currentLocation;
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    currentLocation=location;
    Log.e("lat log", "" + currentLocation.getLatitude() + " , "
            + currentLocation.getLongitude());
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private void stopPeriodicUpdates() {
    mLocationClient
            .removeLocationUpdates((com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);
}

private void startPeriodicUpdates() {

    mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,(com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);
}
```

}

This is my activity code

```
public class MainActivity1 extends Activity {
Loc l;
TextView t;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity1);
    t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
    l = new Loc(getApplicationContext());
    l.start();
}

public void getLoc(View v) {
    // l.getLocation();
     l.startUpdates();
}
```

I am getting my lat and long perfectly fine.
But my issue is with for location updates

I get this error

```
             Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.gps.Loc cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener
```

I do get that I cannot pass LocationListener like this

```
   mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,(com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);
```

But how should I exactly pass it??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only needed to add the interface

```
    com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener
```

Comment: Worked awesome!! Perfect mate! Thanks

Comment: This can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28261754/where-should-i-request-location-updates-in-a-service

Answer (score 0):

like this.

```
public class Loc implements 
GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks
,GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
,com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {
    //...
}
```