# How to Resume LocationServices to request location updates in onResume Method

Tags: android, google-maps, onresume, location-services, android-fusedlocation

My app uses `Google Maps Api`, to display user's current location and seems to be working fine except for two issues:

1 User's location is not being updated in realtime unless app is relaunched.

2 I don't know how to resume `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi` in `onResume` method, hence once user leaves the app, GPS does not restart.

I tried following most of the suggestions found in tutorials and similar questions on this site (like this [Where should I request location updates in A service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28261754/where-should-i-request-location-updates-in-a-service)) but nothing has worked for my case so far.

Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
{

private static final int ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
GoogleMap mMap;

private GoogleApiClient mLocationClient;
private LocationListener mListener;
private View view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (servicesOK()) { // If map is available, load it.
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        if (initMap()){
            mLocationClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
            mLocationClient.connect();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Map not connected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}

public boolean servicesOK (){
    // Checks if GooglePlayServices (Google Map) connection is established
    int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        return true;
    } else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)) {
        Dialog dialog =
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable, this, ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST);
        dialog.show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Mapping unsuccessful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean initMap() {
    if (mMap == null) {
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mMap = mapFragment.getMap();
    }
    return (mMap != null);
}

private void gotoLocation(double lat, double lng) {
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
}

public void showCurrentLocation(MenuItem item) {
    Location currentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
            .getLastLocation(mLocationClient);

    if (currentLocation == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Couldn't connect to map!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("Hello", "Couldn't connect to map" + "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!********************************");

    } else {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(
                currentLocation.getLatitude(),
                currentLocation.getLongitude()
        );
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                latLng, 15
        );
        mMap.animateCamera(update);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    // Executed when connection is successful
    Toast.makeText(this, "Map ready!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Location currentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
            .getLastLocation(mLocationClient);

    LatLng latLng1 = new LatLng(
            currentLocation.getLatitude(),
            currentLocation.getLongitude()
    );

    //Adds Marker when map is connected!
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng1).visible(true).title("Me!")              .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_VIOLET));
    mMap.addMarker(options);

    mListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            "Location changed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            gotoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        }
    };

        // Requests user's current location
    LocationRequest request = LocationRequest.create();
    request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    request.setInterval(10000); // TODO: 11/12/15 Change this to 90000 (90 secs)!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    request.setFastestInterval(3000); // TODO: 11/12/15 Change this to 60000 (60 secs)!!!!!!!!!
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mLocationClient, request, mListener
    );
}

@Override
protected void onPause() { // Stops location updates
    super.onPause();
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
            mLocationClient, mListener
    );
    Log.d("Hello", "The map has been paused!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!********************************");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() { // Resumes location updates
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("Hello", "The map has been resumed!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!********************************");

//Moves camera to user's current location!
        LocationRequest request = LocationRequest.create();
        request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        Location currentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                .getLastLocation(mLocationClient);
        if (currentLocation == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Couldn't connect to map!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(
                    currentLocation.getLatitude(),
                    currentLocation.getLongitude()
            );
            CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    latLng, 15
            );
            mMap.animateCamera(update);
        }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    // Executed when connection is stopped
    Log.d("Hello", "The connection was suspended!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!********************************");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
// Executed when connection is unsuccessful
    Log.d("Hello", "The connection failed!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!********************************");
}
```

}

Comment: I edited my Activity class to show only relevant code wrt to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem by using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9666684/4924793).

Rather than `onResume()` (which didn't work for me after weeks of trying), I used `onRestart()`

```
@Override
protected void onRestart(){
    super.onRestart();
    onConnected(Bundle.EMPTY);
}
```

And it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

I think you should call again the

```
 LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
        mLocationClient, request, mListener);
```

in the onResume() method and make the LocationRequest request global

Comment: Thanks @Melvin Mauricio, I did as you suggested but the app crashes on launch, and strangely no error is indicated in logcat. Just to be sure, does making the `LocationRequest` global simply mean declaring `LocationRequest request;` in the `MainActivity`?

Comment: Check first your google api client if it is connect googleApiclient.isConnected() and if it is request perform the method

Comment: Please could you break it down for me? How exactly do I do that?

Comment: I need the whole Activity class

Comment: I updated my question to include the whole Activity class. My apologies for replying so late.

Answer (score 1):

You are not starting LocationUpdates in your activity at all. Start it in onConnected(). Refer [here](http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html#updates).

Once you start location updates, in onResume() you just need to check that GoogleApiClient is connected as well as requestingLocationUpdates has initialized and you start locationUpdates. See [this](http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html#stop-updates).

PS: your code has other inconsistencies too though, you should probably read the whole guide once and understand the methods accurately.

Comment: I appreciate your comment. Could you please point out some of the inconsistencies. I'm still a newbie and I need all the help I can get.